# Автоматическое возведение строки в UTF8

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Имеется функция:

```
void add_str( std::string s )
{
    c_dv.push_back( s );
}
```

Но, эта строчка получается без utf8.

Вот пример строки с utf8 (вручную)

```
u8"Строчка с utf8"
```

Нужно автоматически подставлять, если можно так сказать, u8 к строчке.

Comment: Строку нужно конвертировать, для этого нужно знать исходную кодировку строки и, скорее всего, использовать стороннюю библиотеку для выполнения конвертации, т.к. в C++ для этого слишком мало средств.

Comment: Я точно не знаю, но думаю что можно написать макрос который будет добавлять u8 ко всем строкам

Comment: Ну подставьте `u8` к строке в Вашей функции и посмотрите, что из этого выйдет.

Comment: Не совсем понял

Comment: Как вы определили, что *"строчка получается без utf8"*?

Comment: Банально вывожу текст, если без utf8 - получаются вопросы вместо кириллицы, если добавляю u8, все нормально

Comment: В какой кодировке у вас код сохранен? Что если заменить ее на utf8?

Comment: Ничего не изменится, я могу выводить даже динамические переменные, все дело в u8

Answer (score -1):

У Вас строка, которая передаётся в s, превращается в вопросики ДО вызова этой функции. И, судя по всему, самим компилятором - а то, что испорчено уже на этапе компиляции, во время исполнения программы Вы не исправите.

Comment: Личное мнение - это скорее комментарий, чем ответ. Случай пограничный, так что подождём ещё мнений.